# MVC website on IIS server issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

MVC 4 website developed in .net 4.5, vs 2012 express on win8
it works fine on local-host

but deployed on web (see [link](http://dev3.codersdigest.com/)) have many errors

1. not all image get rendered
2. CSS font not working properly.
3. when i click logo in HTML source it give mi 404 not found (all resources are present some get renders and some not)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked all your MIME types in IIS to ensure that you're able to serve .PNGs? Just checking...

Which CSS font are you referring to?